# How do I plot data by splitting it unto 5 second intervals?

Tags: r, time, intervals

I'm completely new to R, and I have been tasked with making a script to plot the protocols used by a simulated network of users into a histogram by a) identifying the protocols they use and b) splitting everything into a 5-second interval and generate a graph for each different protocol used.

Currently we have

```
data$bucket <- cut(as.numeric(format(data$DateTime, "%H%M")), 
                c(0,600, 2000, 2359), 
                labels=c("00:00-06:00", "06:00-20:00", "20:00-23:59"))     #Split date into dates that are needed to be
```

to split the codes into 3-zones for another function. 
What should the code be changed to for 5 second intervals?

Sorry if the question isn't very clear, and thank you

Answer (score 2):

The histogram function `hist()` can aggregate and/or plot all by itself, so you really don't need `cut()`.

Let's create 1,000 random time stamps across one hour:

```
set.seed(1)
foo <- as.POSIXct("2014-12-17 00:00:00")+runif(1000)*60*60
```

(Look at `?POSIXct` on how R treats POSIX time objects. In particular, note that "+" assumes you want to add *seconds*, which is why I am multiplying by 60^2.)

Next, define the breakpoints in 5 second intervals:

```
breaks <- seq(as.POSIXct("2014-12-17 00:00:00"),
  as.POSIXct("2014-12-17 01:00:00"),by="5 sec")
```

(This time, look at `?seq.POSIXt`.)

Now we can plot the histogram. Note how we assign the output of `hist()` to an object `bar`:

```
bar <- hist(foo,breaks)
```

(If you don't want the plot, but only the bucket counts, use `plot=FALSE`.)

`?hist` tells you that `hist()` (invisibly) returns the counts per bucket. We can look at this by accessing the `counts` slot of `bar`:

```
bar$counts
[1] 1 2 0 1 0 1 1 2 3 3 0 ...
```